# Integral of $\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

On Wolfram Alpha's website, I find

$$\int\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\frac23 \sqrt{x - \sqrt{1 + x^2}}( {2 x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}})+C$$

I am trying to get this answer by substitution by $x=\tan(\theta), y=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}},$ or  $y={x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. But the integrated  converted to more difficult form .

Comment: Observe that $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$

Comment: But It is positive for some $x$ values.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes *the source of the integral*,  its movitvation, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: @Leonardo: *real* values? No, it isn't. $\sqrt{1+x^2}>|x|$.

Comment: @CarlMummert I don't know the source of question, I saw it on some class board. I tried some substitutions , but it always give me a did end, it is not worth to write the steps.

Comment: The point is that integrating an undefined function is meaningless. But the integral $\int \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}\,dx$ (this makes sense) can be solved through the substitution $x=\tan\theta$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio So the answer of Wolfram is wrong.

Comment: With substitution $t=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ I get an integral of a rational function.  Of course it makes sense to integrate a complex-valued function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Please show me the steps.

Comment: @GEdgar, I don't think the rational function will be easy to solve ( I tried that even with half angle substitution) after making the integral $
\int \sqrt{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}\,dx$

Comment: @Leonardo: it boils down to $\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan(\theta/2)}}{\cos^2\theta}$ or $\int\frac{\sqrt{\tan \theta}}{\cos^2(2\theta)}$ or $\int\frac{\sqrt{t}(1+t^2)}{(1-t^2)^2}$ or $\int\frac{2u^2(1+u^4)}{(1-u^4)^2}$.

Comment: Even easier by directly substituting $x=\sinh v$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leonardo says this will not be easy to solve.  With
$$
t=\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
I get
$$
\int \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}} \;dx = 
-2\int\sqrt{\frac{(t^4-1)^2}{4t^2}+1}\;dt
=-\int \left(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\;dt
$$
and that integral is easy.
$$\begin{align*}
-\int \left(t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)\;dt &= \frac{-t^3}{3}+\frac{1}{t}+C
\\
&=
\frac{-\left( x-\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1} \right) ^{3/2}}{3}+{\frac {1}{\sqrt {x-
\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}}}}+C
\\
&=\frac23 \sqrt{x - \sqrt{1 + x^2}}\big( {2 x + \sqrt{1 + x^2}}\big)+C
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Of course the original integral and this answer are both purely imaginary when $x$ is real.

Comment: I see what I miss.. I really appreciate it. thanks

Comment: I wonder you should push imaginary number front.